# Why Microsoft python analysis engine doesn't recognize some dunders(magic methods)on vs code?Is there an alternative extension to use instead?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, magic-methods

I wrote some magic methods, but Microsoft python extension didn't recognize them and there was no **auto-complete** for them. This methods are **__iter__** and **__getattr__**. 
I tried Jedi engine but it didn't work too. I checked this issue on other users and computers, but this trouble occurred again.
Do you know another auto-complete extension that hasn't got this issue and is more complete than Microsoft python extension?

Look at this experimental code:
[There is no auto-complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXppd.png)

As you can see, there is no auto-complete or recommendation.

Comment: No, it seems like has no better choice, they are improving. BTW, PyCharm can recognize it.

Comment: I'm using kite AI coding assistant ; It's amazing, but it's not free.Thanks for your tips.